# GEOS C error always when creating valid geometry or polygon

Tags: polygon, gdal, geodjango, geos

I am trying to create a Polygon with `django.contrib.gis.geos.Polygon`. I know that the points are valid but I get the error:

```
django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSGeom_createPolygon_r"
```

If I instead use `django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry.GEOSGeometry` it works just fine.

Ex:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon
from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry

poly = GEOSGeometry('POLYGON((4 4, 4 4, 4 4, 4 4))')
poly.coords()
>>> (((4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0), (4.0, 4.0)),)

poly2 = Polygon(((4, 4), (4, 4), (4, 4), (4, 4)))
>>> GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSGeom_createPolygon_r".
```

Operating System & other info:

- MacOS Monterey, M1 chip
- `gdal` installed via homebrew (3.5.1)
- Python 3.8.12, Django 3.2
- also have `geos` and `proj` installed previously as dependencies via homebrew
- Have set:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/libgdal.dylib"`
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/libgeos_c.dylib"
```

Exact same code is working on an older Mac setup w/ the same environment just fine.

Have also now tried Python 3.9 and reinstalling all related brew packages. I also get the same error with other geometry types (`Point` & `LineString` work fine, but `MultiPoint` & `MultiLineString` fail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution here would be to upgrade to Django 4.0.1 or higher after they fixed the bug: https://github.com/django/django/blob/4f284115a9181990f713d5167b25628fa171a5e4/docs/releases/4.0.1.txt#L67-L70

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm trying to get a legacy Django 3.2 project run with a M1 Mac and it seems to be tricky/hard/impossible.

Comment: Back-porting the fix is possible. See commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/19fb838803f63eef0726a370050443b693f109be